# C# cannot return value 'not all code paths return a value' error

Tags: c#, function, return

I have some problems with returning value to function.
I'm returning double and program says "not all code paths return a value"

```
        double calculateSpeed(double isOpponent)
        {
            if (isOpponent == 1)
            {
                double speedY = playerCard.Location.Y / stepY;
                return speedY;
            }
        }
        calculateSpeed(1)
```

Comment: that is because not all code paths do return a value, your function does not have a return statement for when `isOpponent` is not equal to 1

Comment: Oh, thats works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `isOpponent` variable has a value other than `1` no double is returned.

You have to add another `return` statement at the end of your function for the other cases.

The error message 'not all code paths return a value' means, that you don't have a return statement specified for all possible "paths" the program can take.

```c#
double calculateSpeed(double isOpponent)
{
    // Path 1 when `isOpponent == 1`
    if (isOpponent == 1)
    {
        double speedY = playerCard.Location.Y / stepY;
        return speedY;
    }

    // Path 2 when `isOpponent != 1`
    // Here is where you are missing a return statement.
}
calculateSpeed(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error you facing is for condition when isOpponent not equal to 1, in that case you are not returning anything. This is cause of error. So consider returning some value at end of method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comment I added to your code:

```
double calculateSpeed(double isOpponent)
{
     if (isOpponent == 1)
     {
          double speedY = playerCard.Location.Y / stepY;
          return speedY;
     }
     // What should happen here in case the if condition is not true? 
     // You have to return something for that case
}
calculateSpeed(1)
```

As the if-condition possibly will not match, the function will not return anything. So you have to add a return value for that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
you must have 2 return statements.
double calculateSpeed(double isOpponent)
        {
            if (isOpponent == 1)
            {
                double speedY = playerCard.Location.Y / stepY;
                return speedY;
            }
//fix here
             return whatever you want
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`calculateSpeed` function expect double to be return, if your conditions fail then you should return double value. To fix this issue return another double value (may be default speed) outside your if condition

```
    double calculateSpeed(double isOpponent)
    {
        double defaultSpeed = 0;  //Assign default value to this variable
        if (isOpponent == 1)
        {
            double speedY = playerCard.Location.Y / stepY;
            return speedY;
        }
        return defaultSpeed;  //Return default speed if isOpponent is not equal to 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have never returned a value `if isOpponent != 1`.
You need something like this:

```
  double calculateSpeed(double isOpponent)
        {
            if (isOpponent == 1)
            {
                double speedY = playerCard.Location.Y / stepY;
                return speedY;
            }
            else
            {
                return SOMETHING;
            }
        }
        calculateSpeed(1)
```

You can even skip "else" but is less elegant in my opinion.